# "New" Outlook Online closes task pane add-ins

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I've been experiencing a mysterious problem where the task pane hosting my add-in closes completely after code in my add-in sends and receives an XMLHttpRequest - but ONLY with the new Outlook Online UI.  It works perfectly fine in Outlook desktop on Windows and Mac.  There are no exceptions thrown in the web debugger and nothing relevant from my add-in's console logs.  I can set a single breakpoint on random lines of code in various functions across multiple app classes that are run after the button that fires the webrequest is clicked, and the breakpoint gets hit and stops for a second – before the task pane closes completely.  It is very bizarre.

I’ve also ran a network trace of what happens when the task pane disappears, and notice that two requests always occur in the new Outlook Online only (the numbers change but are always sequential):

https://outlook.office.com/owa/service.svc?action=GetConversationItems&n=55&app=Mail
https://outlook.office.com/owa/service.svc?action=GetConversationItems&n=56&app=Mail

I’m guessing that the new Outlook Online is erroneously detecting a context switch of some kind to trigger any open task panes to close.  And note that the task pane NEVER disappears when the task pane is pinned or when the task pane is hosted in a full item window.

Here’s a recording of the task pane disappearing: https://www.screencast.com/t/RO7p0Zu5oP.  *Note how the selection of the current email is also cleared*.

I know I'll be asked to provide a code sample, but given how the add-in has been firing this web request for months without issue until running in the new Outlook Online, I can't see how the problem lies within my code.  Also note that:

- Add-ins cannot close a read item task pane with code, only compose add-ins can (mine is a read mode add-in)
- Only the user changing the message selection should close a task pane (if it is not pinned)
- Add-ins cannot change the message selection
- Any exceptions in the add-in that cause it to crash should be handled by the add-in framework and a message should be displayed in the task pane header (e.g. "This add-in is not responding"). The task pane should NEVER close

Is this happening to anyone else? Can somebody on the Office Dev team confirm that there's no way this scenario should occur?

Comment: We have not seen this kind of issue before, so it would be good if you can provide us the console logs and the network trace for the same.

Comment: How can I send those to you securely? You can DM me at @elegault

Comment: Please paste only the logs indicating an error and feel free to skip / mask any other information in the console log. 

Also, we will be able to help you better, if you can provide us with a simple add-in, which can reproduce this issue.

Based on what you are saying, I would like to know if you are changing the contents of the current mail with the XHR request in the backend.

Comment: The problem is that no error is logged. The task pane closes by some unknown external event. No exceptions are raised in the console. The add-in only reads from the current email and does no modifications. The REST request that is made is to a custom web app and simply requests and receives JSON data. Everything behaves normally except with the new version of Outlook Online. Unfortunately I can't reproduce this with snippets of code for a separate add-in. I can however provide you the login information to an Exchange mailbox that can demonstrate the issue. Would that suffice?

Comment: Yes, that should work for now. If you want to DM me, I think, you will have to create a private room, invite and then message.

Comment: There *was* the chat room that you invited me to (or someone else??), but it has disappeared. But is seems those are public. How can I DM you? I don't see any SO feature for that. You can contact me on Twitter via @elegault, or let me know what your Twitter handle is

Comment: FYI I've been working with MS on this and they have confirmed this is a bug, specifically where if you modify the selected email's properties (e.g. applying a Category) with a Graph call, then the new Outlook Online tries to refresh the email and consequently closes the add-in/task pane.